Error al usar react-router: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
Estoy empezando a adentrarme en el mundo de react, y he llegado a la parte donde estoy probando usar react-router-dom. Tengo al momento solo un componente jsx que carga sin problemas, pero cuando intento implementarlo con react router la consola me man
Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at Object.useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at BrowserRouter (index.tsx:789:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27490:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:1)
react-dom.development.js:18704

The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70886:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.


en contenido de mi App.js es el siguiente:
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<h1> Hola </h1>}  />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;


sin el router carga sin problemas, pero al intentar usarlo me sale solo una ventana en blanco, también intenté creando un archivo jsx aparte e importándolo, pero no lo renderiza, el error que me arroja indica que es un error al intentar usar useRef, pero creo que es algún elemento interno del mismo BrowserRouter.

En la documentación de react router v6, no hay ningún ejemplo que este pasando un elemento HTML a la propiedad element así como se propone en el ejemplo que presentas: element={<h1> Hola </h1>} sugiero que declares un componente que regrese ese elemento h1 y lo pases a la propiedad element, así: <Route path='/' element={<MyH1/>}  /> , por supesto que se asumen que ya instalaste con npm install react-router-dom

también probé con un componente aparte, pero sigue saliendo el error de "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')", importé el componente y la librería de react router

Proporciona la versión que estas usando de react-router, si estas usando vite o create-react-app, version de node js y el archivo index
